# why can't I run my flask server? what is happening with this code here?

Tags: python, flask

```
(env) Lydias-MacBook-Air:flask_class lydiahuang$ ls
README.md   config.py   env     migrations  tests
app     config.pyc  manage.py   requirments.txt
(env) Lydias-MacBook-Air:flask_class lydiahuang$ python manage.py
-bash: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/python: No such file or directory
(env) Lydias-MacBook-Air:flask_class lydiahuang$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

Hi, what's happening with my code here? Why is my Python bin routed to the PHP(MAMP) application route? This doesn't look good, how do I fix this? I can't run my server like this.

Comment: `which pip` should be pointing to the location of your virtualenv's pip. There may be something wrong with your virtual env or other environment variables if that and your python's location is unexpected.

Comment: If you close yout terminal and open a new one, does the problem persist?